# java - Subclasses (childs) fields, Static and Non-Static

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static

I have the following class, `Rocket`, and I want to make subclasses to it, let's say "U1" and "U2".

Now U1 and U2 both have:

- cost
- weight (when empty)
- max weight (max cargo limit)

but these specs are different in both U1 rocket and U2 rocket, although both are "ROCKETS".

How can I declare the specs in the parent class Rocket and give them values in child classes U1 and U2?

Or should I redeclare each in the child classes with their values and skip declaring them at all in the parent class?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help)

, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). 

From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: If the values for these fields are the only differences between your rocket U1 and U2 (if they have no differing unique behaviours in the form of differing methods) then you should model them as *instances* of your class Rocket: `Rocket u1 = new Rocket(cost1, weight1), u2 = new Rocket(cost2, weight2);` Subclasses are only needed when there are different behaviours in the form of different methods or different method implementations.

Comment: start by coding a bit and show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this: `Rocket` class has **protected** `cost, weight, maxWeight` properties. `U1` and `U2` extend it and with their own **public** setters, set their super (Rocket) class properties in any way they want.

```
public class Rocket {
    protected int cost;

    public int getCost(){ return cost;}
}

public class U1 extends Rocket {
    public U1(){ //constructor
        cost = 1; //setting cost of U1 Rocket
    }

    //if public setter is needed, to set cost with any other specs ...
    public void setCost(Specification spec){
        cost = spec.doSomething();
    }
}

public class U1 extends Rocket {
    public U1(){ //constructor
        cost = 2; //setting cost of U2 Rocket
    }

    //if public setter is needed, to set cost with any other specs ...
    public void setCost(Specification spec){
        cost = spec.doSomething();
    }
}
```

by `Specification` I mean any different type of objects that u need to set proper value for cost.

Then if u use something like `Rocket rocket = new U1();` and call `rocket.getCost()` you have cost of an u1 rocket.

but if you are looking to set cost from outside, u should first create new instance of U1 and set cost using the setter, then cast it to Rocket and use rocket.

Also you could use constructor for your super class, Rocket:

```
public class Rocket {
    private int cost;
    public Rocket(int cost){
        this.cost = cost; //avoid shadowing
    }

    public void doSomethingWithCost(){ ... }
    public int getCost() {...}
}

public class U1 extends Rocket {
    public U1(){
        super(1); //setting default cost of U1 Rocket
    }
    public U1(int cost){
        super(cost); //if you need to set the cost when making new instance of U1
    }

}
```

This way you can use values in parent class and you are setting the values in child class.

Though You question is not really clear so I don't expect this to be answer you need. Please make sure u follow the links and comments under your question to learn more about community.

Also, vote my answer as correct if you think it is the answer.